# Centering issue with HTML & CSS

Tags: html, css

currently my issue is this: http://prntscr.com/bhafke
*Browser: Chrome*

For some reason, it's not centering properly. Below you'll find my code:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <h1>Test Text</h1>
    </div> <!-- wrapper div end -->
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `text-align: center;` to center the heading text within the `div`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to center the wrapper or the text inside the wrapper?  If you're just trying to center the wrapper, you're doing that correctly already.  If you're trying to center the text inside the wrapper, you need to add another CSS rule:

```
text-align: center;
```